# Merging fields when doing merge of different layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes, merge

I'm trying to merge 6 points layers, each containing the same fields (Scientific Name, Lat, Long, Count, Common Name) but for different provinces. When I merge the layers, in the geoprocessing wizard, the fields come up in field map as separate for each layer, even though they have the same name. When I completed one of the merges, there would be 2 layers for Common name, for example, with some of the records having "null" in one of the fields and then having data in the other Common Name field. For count, however, this doesn't seem to be a problem.

How do I merge the layers and fields so that all the data from the layers is in just 1 field instead of multiple fields?

Comment: Have you tried using a "Join" rule for the field mapping or adjusted the "add_source" option? More details: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/merge.htm

Comment: thanks for the reply! that seems like it should work, I'm just not sure how to use it. do you know how I could use it to join 2 or more fields?

Comment: Append would be a better choice. The fields should not be duplicated if they have the same names.